# ffmpeg produces the same output file with different bitrate settings

Tags: ffmpeg, bitrate, hevc

My input is an uncompressed video captured from old Hi8 cassettes, mediainfo:

```
Format                                   : RGB
Codec ID                                 : V_UNCOMPRESSED
Codec ID/Info                            : Raw uncompressed video frames
Duration                                 : 1 h 32 min
Width                                    : 720 pixels
Height                                   : 576 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 5:4
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Standard                                 : PAL
```

I have looked at the sources I could find and tried to come up with the optimal settings for my encoding needs, while also trying out a few dozen combinations, and the best I could come up with looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -vf yadif -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset slow -rc:v vbr_hq -cq:v 19 -b:v 2m -maxrate:v 3m -bufsize:v 1m -c:a copy out.mp4
```

The output's mediainfo is:

```
Format                                   : HEVC
Format/Info                              : High Efficiency Video Coding
Format profile                           : Format Range@L3@Main
Codec ID                                 : hev1
Codec ID/Info                            : High Efficiency Video Coding
Duration                                 : 20 s 0 ms
Bit rate                                 : 5 142 kb/s
Width                                    : 720 pixels
Height                                   : 576 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 5:4
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Standard                                 : PAL
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:4:4
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.496
Stream size                              : 12.3 MiB (97%)
Codec configuration box                  : hvcC
```

What I have found is that I can increase the `-b:v 2m -maxrate:v 3m -bufsize:v 1m` options tenfold, and the output still stays the same. How can this be the case? I am thinking I messed up the settings gravely, in this case, could you please correct me and set me to the right ballpark? First I tried without the bitrate options and only `-rc:v vbr_hq -cq:v 19`, but that resulted in terrible quality and smaller size, and then I found that I need to set the bitrate as well, unlike just the `-crf` like I used to do with `libx265`.

Abandoning `-preset slow` also doesn't change the result.

I have also tried `libx265`, which I have used beforehand, but that's a 10-20x speed decrease, so I wouldn't want to use it for this 15+ hour project. One thing I see is that with that the chroma subsamplig is `4:2:2`, instead of `4:4:4`. Setting it to `4:2:0` actually increases the file size, what should I do with this?

Thank you in advance for any help, and please let me know if I should give more information in order to get the help I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With hevc_nvenc, if `cq:v` is set, `b:v` is ignored. Change `-cq:v` in conjunction with `-maxrate:v` instead.

Comment: Thank you, now I know! After I read your solution, I tried different settings, and found out that the problem is that I was using `m` instead of `M`, resulting in those options basically getting ignored... Shouldn't this be raised as en error by ffmpeg? It certainly throws an error if I only give it a string... I managed to find the default `maxrate` and `bufsize` settings, which were `4.8M` and `4M` respectively, and I just increased the bufsize, the bitrate seems good. Thank you again!